# Willingness to share ideas that could turn into a paper

Tags: reference-request

Is there any research/study/survey that looked at researchers' willingness to publicly share ideas that could potentially turn into a paper?

Comment: I downvoted because I don't think this is an answerable question. I do not know what you mean by "looked at researchers' willingness". I cannot think of which field you imagine such a study might have been carried out in. I cannot tell what sort of answer would satisfy you. Frankly, it feels like your real question is "hey, let's chat about willingness to share ideas" and the first clause is tacked on solely to make this look like a question suitable for this Q&A site (which is not a discussion forum).

Comment: @TomChurch Did you see the question tag? Only looking for references.

Comment: @TomChurch regarding your first interrogation on willingness, see https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=willingness

Comment: I'd love to have a special SE site for finding references for academic papers

Comment: Yes, this very question is research by you in this matter :) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that somebody should expect people here on *Acedemia.SE* to perform literature search for them (regardless of their motivation for a question), hence the feedback you've received so far. Having said that, I have *briefly* looked at the topic and have selected the following **references** that might be of your interest. The **caveats** are as follows: 1) the references below are intended to be used mainly not as primary sources, but as *containers* of more relevant references; 2) *scope* of the studies referenced below ranges from some specific context to more general knowledge sharing;

- Keyes, Jessica. [Identifying the Barriers to Knowledge Sharing in Knowledge Intensive Organizations](http://www.newarttech.com/KnowledgeSharing.pdf). ProQuest, 2008.
- Wang, Sheng, and Raymond A. Noe. "[To Share or Not to Share: Is That the Question?](http://er.educause.edu/articles/2010/8/to-share-or-not-to-share-is-that-the-question)" Human Resource Management Review 20.2 (2010): 115-131.
- Pilerot, Ola. "[A practice theoretical exploration of information sharing and trust in a dispersed community of design scholars](http://www.informationr.net/ir/18-4/paper595.html)" Information Research 18.4 (2013): 18-4.
- Wang, Sheng, and Raymond A. Noe. "[Knowledge sharing: A review and directions for future research](http://www.ucdenver.edu/academics/colleges/CLAS/Centers/writing/Documents/HR_Managament.pdf)" Human Resource Management Review 20.2 (2010): 115-131.

Comment: Thanks! Yes sorry admission questions are much more interesting. Surprisingly there is a reference-request tag with over 100 questions.

Comment: This is a better answer to this question that I thought was possible -- really excellent.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: You're welcome! In my opinion, the `reference-request` tag should be used either for help with finding some unique references on rare topics, or, at least, when one have tried everything, exhausted all options and came up with nothing and stuck.

Comment: @TomChurch: Your kind words are greatly appreciated.